# How to tell latex which package version to use

Tags: packages

I'm currently writing a document on my "work-pc" meaning, that I do not have sudo rights on this machine.

It has some old version of hyperref installed, that is not compatible with pdfx and gives me the error:
hyperref.sty: Package xkeyval error: 'pdfa' undefined in families Hyp.

I have downloaded a newer version of hyperref.sty from ctan and put it in a local directory. Then I have added said directory to the $TEXINPUTS variable, hoping that it would now use the newer hyperref version.

However it still uses the old one in /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty which I don't have permissions to alter. How do I get it to use my new local version?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that as well.  :)
I also remembered in the mean time that one can put the package in ~/texmf/tex as this is queried first, so this can be considered solved.... Wish I had remembered this 10seconds before I posted, not after :p

Comment: Setting TEXINPUTS is the answer. presumably you did not add it correctly, but hard to say as you didn't show the value.

Comment: In addition to what David says, have you got the correct layout for your local directory (`<place>/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty`)

Comment: @JosephWright Yes. Once I've moved it to ~/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty it worked. I only remembered to try this after posting here, unfortunately.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle An answer?

Answer (score 4):

If you set

```
TEXINPUTS=/your/local/directory:
```

Then Tex will look there first and then (because of the trailing `:` ) look in all the standard places.

You can set TEXINPUTS as an environment variable or as a value in a `texmf.cnf` file.